# Silverlight XML Save does not overwrite the entire file

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, save

The best way to explain my problem is by a example.

I have a Xml file with some elements in it. When I remove a element, I save the file again and this problem occurs:

**Before save**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ElementTree>
  <Elements1 />
  <Elements2>
    <Element Name="TestElement" ID="4efa7cc9-a89a-429b-81f4-b00cde729f24" />
  </Elements2>
  <Elements3 />
</ElementTree>
```

**After save**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ElementTree>
  <Elements1 />
  <Elements2 />
  <Elements3 />
</ElementTree>D="4efa7cc9-a89a-429b-81f4-b00cde729f24" />
  </Elements2>
  <Elements3 />
</ElementTree>
```

What I suspect it is doing: It keeps writing the text untill it has reached the end of the text to be saved and then it stops. It does not remove the text that is still writen in the file AFTER the last character in the stream.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I've run into problems like this before, in other contexts. You could delete the existing file before creating a new one?

Comment: see my comment at Emo's answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you [replace the existing file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.95%29) when opening it and you close the stream correctly.

Comment: using (var stream = file.OpenFile("Films.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))

Changing FileMode.Open to FileMode.Create fixed this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Next time you ask a question make sure you post the code you are using. That would have made answering this question much easier.