# Incorrect structured XML document after deleting element

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

When I try to load a `XML` file after deleting an `Element` from the file, it shows the following error: `Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 9, position 10.` What is wrong with my code?

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <booze>booze1</booze>
   <booze>booze2</booze>
   <booze>booze3</booze>
   <booze>booze4</booze>
</data>
```

And my code:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("favorites.xml", FileMode.Open, file))
   {
       XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);
       // delete node
       xDoc.Descendants("data").Elements("booze").Where(x => x.Value == favorite).DescendantsAndSelf().Remove();
       xDoc.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is at Line 9, position 10 ? There's nothing else in your xml file is there? (Because there's only 7 lines in what you are showing us) You don't have some comments before the <?xml do you?

Comment: I think the "DescendantsAndSelf()" extension causes the <data> tag to be removed, hence the resultant XML has no root.

Comment: @PaulZahra The weird thing is that mentions that line and position no matter how many elements I have in my file. Even if there is only 1 element left after deleting a 2nd..

Comment: @bit It doesn't remove the `<data>` tag because if I add a breakpoint to the line with `xDoc.save(stream);` and inspect the `xDoc`, it shows a correct document in my eyes..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight XML Save does not overwrite the entire file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032253/silverlight-xml-save-does-not-overwrite-the-entire-file)

Comment: @PaulZahra Possibly not an exact duplicate since he does not want to clear the file on open, he wants to clear it on write. I think that the solution provided on that question will not work for him as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that when you run the code for the first time, the delete succeeds and your XDoc contains : 
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <data>
      <booze>booze1</booze>
      <booze>booze2</booze>
      <booze>booze4</booze>
    </data>`

, but when calling XDoc.Save you simply append this to the *favorites.xml* file. After that, the *favorites.xml* file contains something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <booze>booze1</booze>
   <booze>booze2</booze>
   <booze>booze3</booze>
   <booze>booze4</booze>
</data><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <booze>booze1</booze>
  <booze>booze2</booze>
  <booze>booze4</booze>
</data>
```

That is why all the subsequent file loads throw the error. What you should do is overwrite the file, and not append to it. The first way of doing that that comes to mind is to close the stream, open it with Mode.Truncate and then save the XDoc. Or you can delete and recreate the file. I am not that familiar with IsolatedStorageFiles so this is a wild guess.

Comment: Ok, already thought about something like that. But how can I solve that? Clearing the `stream`? And how can I do that?

Comment: Because of the 'using' statement and the 'new' I doubt that this happens.

Comment: @PaulZahra I'd recommend for JelleKerkstra to try and create a new clear file and see if the append happens on XDoc.Save().

Comment: @Solver After looking into it a bit more I think your are correct, a quick test I think is to change FileMode.Open to FileMode.Create so that it overwrites the file instead of appending, look at this possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032253/silverlight-xml-save-does-not-overwrite-the-entire-file

Comment: @PaulZahra I believe that FileMode.Create will overwrite the file on load, and you won't be able to read the XML. A possible option could be to use two streams. One stream to load the file (FileMode.Open) and one stream to write to the file (FileMode.Create). That would effectively read the file and then recreate it after the modifications have been made.

Comment: Can't get any combinations with FileMode.Create or Open and FileAcces.Write. So I'll just do a workaround by creating an empty xml document and insert the remaining elements. not the most elegant solution but it will work I hope

Comment: @JelleKerkstra Have you tried opening the file with FileMode.Open, loading it in your document with XDoc.Load, closing the filestream, modifying the XDoc, opening a new fileStream with FileMode.Create, and saving with the second filestream? In that order? :) I see no reason why that should fail...

Comment: @Solver Yay, followed you last comment and it works now!! Thanks a lot!!